# Elasticsearch: NoShardAvailableActionException after startup

Tags: java, exception, elasticsearch

I start my Java-application and Elasticsearch 1.4.2 via upstart. Sometimes when I restart my server I get a `NoShardAvailableActionException` within the first 5 doc requests.

My application first read some docs from Elasticsearch and Elasticsearch doesn't seem to be ready. When I wait a little bit and restart my app, everything works.

How can I check if my Elasticsearch cluster (I have just 1 node) is ready to get docs?

I have already tried to check the cluster status, but even it is already yellow, I get sometimes the `NoShardAvailableActionException`:

```
private static void checkClusterStateNotRed() throws Exception {
    while(clusterState() == ClusterHealthStatus.RED) {
        Logger.info("Elasticsearch cluster state is red);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}

private static ClusterHealthStatus clusterState() throws Exception {
    return ElasticsearchClient.getInstance()
            .admin().cluster()
            .clusterStats(new ClusterStatsRequest())
            .get()
            .getStatus();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I feel you are not waiting for the shards to be recovered and ready to be open for requests. Usually it takes some time.

```
client.admin().cluster().prepareHealth().setWaitForYellowStatus().execute().actionGet(5000)
```

Use this code before making any calls. This will wait for at-least 5 seconds before the shards are fully recovered and the cluster is back to at-least yellow status.